# Dynamically run strings in a loop

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I want to run a string dynamically.

I'm trying to run a VBA loop to build a SQL Union for each record after the first. There could be anywhere from 1 record to 100. I want this to be dynamic so I don't have to limit the number of entries.

Example:
If I have 5 records it creates the SQL query with 4 unions. All the same data etc.

I'm trying to do is this:
When someone opens a form they will enter a list of pack numbers, from that they will select the range of offers under each pack number (All Offers, Promo, or Buyer).
The code then builds a union query for each pack number based on the the offer range they selected.
The output is all the data on those Offers under that pack number.

My full code: (I thought it necessary to get the full picture)

```vb
Private Sub ReviewButton_Click()
Dim Owner As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdfPassThrough As QueryDef
Dim strSeasonSQL As String
Dim strSeason As String
Dim strType As String

Owner = GetNamespace("MAPI").Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry

        If Me.NewRecord = True Then
            Me!Owner.Value = Owner
        End If
        
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("RetailEntry")
'Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM RetailEntry")

strSeason = [Forms]![Retail_Navigation]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cboSeason]
strType = rs.Fields("Offer").Value '[Forms]![ReviewButton]![RetailEntry].[Form]![Offer].Value

On Error GoTo 1
1:

'Build Initial Query based on first record and make sure there are records
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
rs.MoveFirst

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'All Offers
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If rs.Fields("Offer") = "All Offers" Then
        StrSQL = "Set NoCount ON DROP TABLE #catcov; " _
            & "SELECT DISTINCT mailyear, offer, description, firstreleasemailed, season_id, offer_type, " _
            & "case when description like '%Promo%' then 'Promo' " _
            & "Else 'Buyer' end As addtype " _
            & "INTO #catcov " _

        strSELECT = "FROM supplychain_misc.dbo.catcov; " _
            & "SELECT DISTINCT " _
            & "a.PackNum " _
            & ",a.Description " _
            & ",a.CatID " _
            & ",DATEPART(QUARTER, FirstReleaseMailed) as Quarter " _
            & ",a.RetOne " _
            & ",a.Ret2 " _
            & ",a.ORIGINALRETAIL " _
            & ",a.DiscountReasonCode " _
            & ",b.Season_id " _
            & ",a.year " _
            & ",addtype "

        strFROM = "FROM PIC704Current a JOIN #CatCov b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer) and (a.Year = b.MailYear) " _

        strWHERE = "WHERE b.Offer_Type In('catalog', 'insert', 'kicker', 'statement insert', 'bangtail', 'onsert', 'outside ad') " _
            & " and b.Season_id = '" & strSeason & "' " _
            & " and (Case when b.FirstReleaseMailed >= cast(dateadd(day, +21, getdate()) as date) then 1 else 0 end) = 1 "

StrSQL = StrSQL & vbCrLf & strSELECT & vbCrLf & strFROM & vbCrLf & strWHERE

'Promo/Core
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
ElseIf rs.Fields("Offer") = "Promo" Or rs.Fields("Offer") = "Buyer" Then
        StrSQL = "Set NoCount ON DROP TABLE #catcov; " _
            & "SELECT DISTINCT mailyear, offer, description, firstreleasemailed, season_id, offer_type, " _
            & "case when description like '%Promo%' then 'Promo' " _
            & "Else 'Buyer' end As addtype " _
            & "INTO #catcov " _
        
        strSELECT = "FROM supplychain_misc.dbo.catcov; " _
            & "SELECT DISTINCT " _
            & "a.PackNum " _
            & ",a.Description " _
            & ",a.CatID " _
            & ",DATEPART(QUARTER, FirstReleaseMailed) as Quarter " _
            & ",a.RetOne " _
            & ",a.Ret2 " _
            & ",a.ORIGINALRETAIL " _
            & ",a.DiscountReasonCode " _
            & ",b.Season_id " _
            & ",a.year " _
            & ",addtype "
      
      strFROM = "FROM PIC704Current a JOIN #CatCov b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer) and (a.Year = b.MailYear) " _
      
      strWHERE = "WHERE b.Offer_Type In('catalog', 'insert', 'kicker', 'statement insert', 'bangtail', 'onsert', 'outside ad') " _
            & " and b.Season_id = '" & strSeason & "' and b.addtype = '" & strType & "' " _
            & " and (Case when b.FirstReleaseMailed >= cast(dateadd(day, +21, getdate()) as date) then 1 else 0 end) = 1 "

StrSQL = StrSQL & vbCrLf & strSELECT & vbCrLf & strFROM & vbCrLf & strWHERE
End If

'Build/Loop Unions for each record after the first
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
rs.MoveNext
strType = rs.Fields("Offer").Value
Do Until rs.EOF = True
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'All Offers
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If rs.Fields("Offer") = "All Offers" Then
        StrUnion = "UNION SELECT DISTINCT " _
            & "a.PackNum " _
            & ",a.Description " _
            & ",a.CatID " _
            & ",DATEPART(QUARTER, FirstReleaseMailed) as Quarter " _
            & ",a.RetOne " _
            & ",a.Ret2 " _
            & ",a.ORIGINALRETAIL " _
            & ",a.DiscountReasonCode " _
            & ",b.Season_id " _
            & ",a.year " _
            & ",addtype "

        strFROMnxt = "FROM PIC704Current a JOIN #CatCov b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer) and (a.Year = b.MailYear) " _

        strWHEREnxt = "WHERE b.Offer_Type In('catalog', 'insert', 'kicker', 'statement insert', 'bangtail', 'onsert', 'outside ad') " _
            & " and b.Season_id = '" & strSeason & "' " _
            & " and (Case when b.FirstReleaseMailed >= cast(dateadd(day, +21, getdate()) as date) then 1 else 0 end) = 1 "

StrSQL2 = StrUnion & vbCrLf & strFROMnxt & vbCrLf & strWHEREnxt

'Promo/Buyer
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
ElseIf rs.Fields("Offer") = "Promo" Or rs.Fields("Offer") = "Buyer" Then
        StrUnion = "UNION SELECT DISTINCT " _
            & "a.PackNum " _
            & ",a.Description " _
            & ",a.CatID " _
            & ",DATEPART(QUARTER, FirstReleaseMailed) as Quarter " _
            & ",a.RetOne " _
            & ",a.Ret2 " _
            & ",a.ORIGINALRETAIL " _
            & ",a.DiscountReasonCode " _
            & ",b.Season_id " _
            & ",a.year " _
            & ",addtype "
      
      strFROMnxt = "FROM PIC704Current a JOIN #CatCov b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer) and (a.Year = b.MailYear) " _
      
      strWHEREnxt = "WHERE b.Offer_Type In('catalog', 'insert', 'kicker', 'statement insert', 'bangtail', 'onsert', 'outside ad') " _
            & " and b.Season_id = '" & strSeason & "' and b.addtype = '" & strType & "' " _
            & " and (Case when b.FirstReleaseMailed >= cast(dateadd(day, +21, getdate()) as date) then 1 else 0 end) = 1 "

StrSQL2 = StrUnion & vbCrLf & strFROMnxt & vbCrLf & strWHEREnxt
End If

'Move to next Record and loop till EOF
rs.MoveNext
Loop

'If there are no Records then error
Else
    MsgBox "There are no Pack Numbers Entered."
End If

'END QUERY
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Build Retail Bump File Pass Through Query
    db.QueryDefs.Delete "qryMaster"
    Set qdfPassThrough = db.CreateQueryDef("qryMaster")
    qdfPassThrough.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=SupplyChainMisc;Description=SupplyChainMisc;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=SupplyChain_Misc;"
    qdfPassThrough.ReturnsRecords = True
    qdfPassThrough.sql = StrSQL & vbCrLf & StrSQL2

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

DoCmd.OpenForm "SubCanButton"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "MasterQuery"

DoCmd.Close acForm, "ReviewButton"

End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to build pass-through queries for _SQL Server_, so print out the finished SQL and run it in _SQL Server Management Studio_ for debugging.

Comment: @Gustav I have done that to make my corrections. I am able to get it to run for a single record, or two records. Once I go above that I have issues and it's because of the StrSQL lines `StrSQL2 = StrQL & vbCrLf & StrUnion & vbCrLf & strFROMnxt & vbCrLf & strWHEREnxt` this is because I don't know how to make this dynamic in such a way that I could run more than 2 records, and this is what I'm trying to figure out if it is possible.

Comment: It might be possible, but it is not possible for me to debug your code, not to say the unknown output.

Comment: Ahh misunderstood what you were saying originally @Gustav I've add the table data the query is building from and I've added the SQL Query data output. Hopefully that helps? Let me know if you have any thoughts or need anything else.

Comment: Data should be provided as text tables, not images. Show desired output as well. AFAIK, UNION has a limit of 50 SELECT lines.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do a "union distinct" when you don't include `ALL`:

```
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

Thus, as your selected records seem the same, only one will returned.

Second, including `ALL` or not, your concept doesn't make much sense. Why union a lot of identical records? Even if they hold different IDs only, they seem to be pulled from the same table, which you could with a single query.

Third, casting a date value to a date value does nothing good, so:

```
cast(dateadd(day, +21, getdate()) as date)
```

can be reduced to:

```
dateadd(day, +21, getdate())
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I've explained what I'm trying to do very well. This is more a programming issue in VBA not SQL. I've re-typed my original question. I want to be able to run a string dynamically based on the recordset in a table. The Unions would be that part that gets built dynamically but there is nothing wrong with the SQL code specifically.

Comment: If you have build a string holding your complete query, you can open a recordset with `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(StrSQL)`.

Comment: Correct which the code I attached shows how I'm currently attempting to do it. The problem is I'm limited to the number of times it runs StrSQL2 to only once. I'm trying to get it to run it for each Pack Number in the record set so if I have 5 pack numbers it runs `StrSQL & StrSQL2  & StrSQL2  & StrSQL2  & StrSQL2` or however many pack numbers there are beyond the first one.

Comment: Then run a loop and, for each pack number, add a query to the SQL. But something tells me, that this is an overly complicated method that might need reconsideration.

Comment: It could be. I'm self taught in programming SQL and VBA but I don't know any other way to do what I'm trying to do. There could be another more efficient way and I have been researching for a few days on this particular problem and so far nothing had stood out. That's why I came here to ask for help. Looks like I may be out of luck and need to just do this the hard way.

Comment: The hard way should just be to create the loop. Else, for SQL, search for `inner join` and filtering on related tables. Union queries are mainly intended to assemble otherwise unrelated data.

Comment: Out of curiosity do you have an idea of what the easy way would be?

Comment: A simple select query joining the two tables. However, we are approaching OT here. You may benefit from posting your question and code - and perhaps attach a sample db with representative data - at [UtterAccess](https://utteraccess.com/).